# jqGrid - use combo box options for search criteria

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid

We are using jqGrid search - for a given field, how can you specify a combo box with specific search values instead of a text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to use `stype` and `searchoptions`:

```
{name:'expiry', index:'expiry', width:60, align:'right',stype:'select', searchoptions:{dataUrl:'expiry_select.htm'}}
```

More info [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config)

Comment: Currently search dialog has support **only for the text and select types**. I suggested Tony (see http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/editrules-in-serach-dialog/) to rewrite Search Dialog to use the code used currently in edit dialog and inline editing. Then checkboxes and all other controls inclusive custom controls could be used. It seems that the suggestion is forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
colModel:[
  ... 
  {name:'MyField',index:'MyField', width:80, align:"right", stype:'select', editoptions:{value:":All;0.00:0.00;12:12.00;20:20.00;40:40.00;60:60.00;120:120.00"}},
```